# is there a way to check if a param contains a class or a class instance?

Tags: python, typechecking

I want the wrapper my_function to be able to receive either a class or class instance, instead of writing two different functions:

```
>>> from module import MyClass

>>> my_function(MyClass)

True

>>> cls_inst = MyClass()

>>> my_function(cls_inst)

True
```

the problem is that I don't know in advance which type of classes or class instances I am going to receive. So I can't, for example, use functions like isinstance...

How can I type check if a param contains a class or a class instance, in a generic way?

Any idea?

Comment: Could you provide a use case for doing this?  It doesn't make a lot of sense on the surface.  Why can't you use `my_function( object.__class__ )` so that things are at least consistent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> class A: pass

>>> isinstance(A, type)
True
>>> isinstance(A(), type)
False
```

Comment: Your example is an old-style class, but this does also work with new-style classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
import types

def myfun(maybe_class):
    if type(maybe_class) == types.ClassType:
        print "It's a class."
    else:
        print "It's an instance."
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the type() buitlin function.

E.g.:

```
import avahi
print type(avahi)

<type 'module'>
```